# Getting user input for the purpose of encoding into Paypal custom variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

I'm trying to create a form that scoops up a bunch of user information, stores it in an array, json encodes it, and passes it to Paypal via Paypal's custom variable in a Paypal button. Here is the way it works right now.

```
<?php
    $firstName = "Lucas";
    $lastName = "Harvmaster";
    $email = "shrike321@hotmail.com";
    $companyName = "Matchbox";
    $password = "123Cupcakes";
    $arr = array('firstName' => $firstName, 'lastName' => $lastName, 'email' => $email, 'companyName' => $companyName, 'password' => $password);
    $data = json_encode($arr);
?>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input name="custom" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $data ?>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="89924XE27QRNY">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This does work, but it leaves me with an issue. How do I go about setting the php variables dynamically based on what the user enters in a form, rather than just hard coding them? It seems like there really isn't any way to bake that functionality into the paypal form, because I need to gather the data from the user, then compile it together, than pass it to paypal which seems like I need two forms so I can do things with the variables in the middle. I'm wondering about just creating a confirmation page of some sort that I can pass form fields too and host the paypal button on that page? But I suspect there might be other ways of solving the problem that neither me nor my google-fu has dug up. Thanks in advance :)

Edit:  Here is what I'm trying to do with Javascript. I'm incredibly new to Javascript and the code tells me I do not have permission to access the paypal when I run it. I likely haven many errors, my lack of familiarity with Javascript is apparent :)

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
Company name: <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName">
Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password">

<script>
    var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstName")[0].value;
    var lastName = document.getElementsByName("lastName")[0].value;
    var email = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;
    var companyName = document.getElementsByName("companyName")[0].value;
    var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
    var output = JSON.stringify(firstName, lastName, email, companyName, password);
</script>

<input name="custom" type="hidden" value='<script>output</script>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 10 different ways to do this, including using client-side javascript instead of PHP to encode the value of `custom` -- so that it can all happen on the client side in a single form, rather than as a 2 step process.

And using [a smart button](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) would provide a much nicer experience than the old legacy buttons that redirect away from your site.

How complex an overall solution you choose will depend on your needs. It's hard to go into any particular detail without knowing anything more about your solution's needs (things not discussed in your question), since there are at least 10 different ways to do solve this problem.

But well, for something particular the JavaScript equivalent to do all the above on the client side is `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It makes sense to me that client side javascript would be able to do this, though my lack of familiarity with JS is going to bite me in the butt here. I've updated my question with what I tried, but I'm very confident it's very out to lunch.

Comment: JS is event-driven, and the basic problem with your code before the last line is that there's no event to call it at the appropriate time, once the user has filled out the text fields.  This would be an easy if you were using a the JS smart button; you chould just stick the JSON.stringify() in the appropriate place.  But since you don't have an appropriate place, you'd have to write an onSubmit event for your form, which is complex for someone who doesn't know JS